# Unable to get parent Entity when child is marked deleted with ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm using ef core 2.0 to access a Sql Server database. This project has a basic soft delete requirement, so i i've defined a filter for all Entities like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasQueryFilter(e => !e.IsDeleted);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasQueryFilter(e => !e.IsDeleted);
    ...
}
```

The classes represented above were defined as following:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public partial class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Then i'm trying to get a list of employees (or a single employee) and if the associated company has IsDeleted set to true, the employee is not retrieved.

The query is the following:

```
var query = context.Employee
                   .Include(i => i.Company)
                   .Include(i => i.EmployeeType)
                   .Include(i => i.EmployeeEquipment)
                      .ThenInclude(w => w.Equipment)
                   .Where(i => i.Id == (Guid) id);
var employeeFiltered =  await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

So this query don't retrieved the employee if the Company associated is marked with IsDeleted property to true which is not the expected behaviour. What i would like is to get the Employee with Company set to null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From relational standpoint `Company` is the *parent* and `Employee` is the *child*. Hence it's normal to not retrieve employees of a deleted company.

Comment: since the entites are not really deleted, but only softdeleted with a "isDeleted" flag the only suitable and right answer is the one posted by MustafaOmar. Your .HasQueryFilter(e => !e.IsDeleted) is getting applied by each select, so you need to disable it. Please update your answer to accept the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post title is misleading, because from relational standpoint `Company` entity is the *parent* (a.k.a. principal, owner, referenced) and `Employee` is the *child* (a.k.a. dependent, owned, referencing).

Still what you are asking is possible, but only if the relationship is [*optional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships), i.e. the dependent entity could exist without principal entity. In your case it's *required* because the FK property type does not allow null value, so to make it optional, you need to change the FK property type to the corresponding nullable type:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; } // <--
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `.IgnoreQueryFilter()` to the query like this.

```
var query = context.Employee
               .IgnoreQueryFilter()
               .Include(i => i.Company)
               .Include(i => i.EmployeeType)
               .Include(i => i.EmployeeEquipment)
                  .ThenInclude(w => w.Equipment)
               .Where(i => i.Id == (Guid) id);
var employeeFiltered =  await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```